# Page numbering different side of heading for odd and even page

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, fancyhdr

Hello I am using a `fancyhdr` package and I want that the page number appear in the right side of the heading for odd pages and in the left side of the heading for the left side. I alredy used the command `\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\thepage}` but it does not work. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[twoside,12pt]{elsarticle}%
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{thmdefs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{30}
\providecommand{\U}[1]{\protect\rule{.1in}{.1in}}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\newenvironment{proof}[1][Proof]{\noindent\textbf{#1.} }{\ \rule{0.5em}{0.5em}}
\newtheorem{condition}[theorem]{Condition}

\journal{}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\newcommand\shorttitle{------------------------------}
\newcommand\authors{--------------------------}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\fancyhead[C]{%
\ifodd\value{page}
  \small\scshape\authors
\else
  \small\scshape\shorttitle
\fi }

\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\thepage}

\begin{document}
HELLO!!!!
\end{document}
```

I think it is something related to the class `elsarticle`, because if I change to another the class everything works well.

Comment: If you're submitting an article to an Elsevier journal, they will override such settings before it is published. If you're not, why not use another document class?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 5):

The `elsarticle` class doesn't use `twoside`, so there's no way for `fancyhdr` to distinguish between the two cases.

Use a trick similar to the one you're using for alternating title and author: if the page number is even, push the page number all the way to the left with `\hfill`.

On the other hand, if you're submitting the paper to Elsevier, such changes shouldn't be made.

```
\documentclass[twoside,12pt]{elsarticle}%
\usepackage[margin=0.5in,headheight=14.5pt,includehead]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\journal{}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\newcommand\shorttitle{------------------------------}
\newcommand\authors{--------------------------}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\fancyhead[C]{%
\ifodd\value{page}
  \small\scshape\authors
\else
  \small\scshape\shorttitle
\fi }

\fancyhead[R]{\thepage\ifodd\value{page}\else\hfill\fi}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

[image]