# How would you implement this style of header?

Tags: header-footer

First page   --->number and name of journal

[image]

Second page  --->title and page

[image]

Thrid page is like the first etc...

Comment: Near duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109654/page-numbering-different-side-of-heading-for-odd-and-even-page

Comment: @Marijn - Not all that much of a duplicate, IMNSHO: The older posting was concerned importantly with how to get the `fancyhdr` machinery with the `elsarticle` document class (which doesn't handle the document class `twoside`).

Comment: @Mico The answer to the older post is indeed not relevant here, but the question itself (nearly) solves the problem of the current post, particularly in showing the use of `\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\thepage}`. Granted, your solution below solves the problem much nicer and without distractions, but the other post could at least serve to point the OP towards `fancyhdr` (welcome, @user10699 !) and let him continue from there. Also: H is what keeps TeX.SE nice.

Comment: @Marijn - points well taken! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use the `fancyhdr` package.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}\fancyfoot{} % clear all header and footer fields
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % no header rule
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[CE]{\em The Journal of Finance}
\fancyhead[CO]{\em The American Put Option and Its Critical Stock Price}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for filler text
\begin{document}

\setcounter{page}{2334}
\lipsum[1-15] % generate 3 pages of text
\end{document}
```

Comment: what if you want to skip the first 2 pages (front page and table of contents page in my case ) ?

Comment: @user10699 - You could provide the instruction `\thispagestyle{plain}` (or, if you prefer, `\thispagestyle{empty}` on each of the first two pages.

Comment: I made a mistake its not showing up on my first page but it is showing up on my toc. i will try your solution now. thank you

Comment: USING the `\usepackage[margin=1.5in]{geometry}` i find that the page number is not inline with the margin. where can i change the p.numer margin ?

Comment: @user10699 - Does the instruction `\usepackage[margin=1.5in]{geometry}` come before or after the fancyhdr-related code? It should come *before* the fancyhdr-related code...